# Build only changed item or build all ,which is preferred in continuous integration?

Tags: build, msbuild, continuous-integration, build-process, teamcity

Our software is split into multiple components.

Msbuild scripts automate our build and batch scripts to invoke it.
We are taking the daily build of our components even if we have small changes.
We want to move to continuous integration so that whenever a check-in happens a build is triggered.

Our msbuild scripts are written in such a way that it will build all the sln files for the component.
In continuous integration, do I only need to build the slns that are modified?

If I only build the changed items, do I have to write a msbuild for each sln?

Can I simply use the existing msbuild script in teamcity?

Comment: This is a very subjective question.  What is the requirement of your software - your environment - your deployment?

Answer (score 5):

I have done both, and there are advantages and disadvantages to both:

### Incremental Build (only what's changed)

This is the default behavior of MSBuild. Even when you build in Visual Studio, it only builds what changed (unless you choose "Rebuild All").

#### Pros

- **Faster** The faster your feedback loop, the better.
- **Less load on build server disk and network** since you don't have to check everything out of source control each time. This may be important in high load build clusters.

#### Cons

- **Possible Source Control Hiccups** We have had issues where a complicated rename or restructuring of our source tree caused the checkout to fail. We were using subversion, so it was the update that failed. Had we been doing a clean checkout, this would not have happened (of course a clean checkout means we must do a full rebuild).
- **Chance of false positives.** We had a case where we weren't completely wiping the build agent's source files and checking out fresh copies from source. Someone changed the build file such that it didn't copy the binaries properly before testing them, but since the old binaries were still there on the disk, it was running the tests from them. The build was broken, but it was running old binary tests, so we didn't realize we had introduced bugs until I spotted the problem a week later.

### Full Checkout and Rebuild

#### Pros

- **More Robust** You rule out source control update issues and the chance of false positives becuase you are starting with a clean slate each and every time. This removes the possiblity that a previous build could affect this build.

#### Cons

- **Much Slower** This involves waiting for a full checkout from source, which may take a long time if the project is large. Plus it requires building the entire source tree from scratch.
- **Higher Load on Build Agent, Disk & Network** Because you are checking out and rebuilding everything, you will tax the cpu and disk of the build agent more, and also of the network (and your source control system as well).

### Third Option: Incremental Checkout and Rebuild

This is the case where you only pull incremental changes from source control, but perform a full rebuild.

#### Pros

- **Faster than full checkout** and is actually only slightly slower than incrementally building. Build times are usually small compared to the time it takes to do a full checkout, or run your tests.
- **Somewhat more robust** since you rebuild all the source, but false positives can still sneak in.

#### Cons

- **Possible Source Control Hiccups** See my comments on the Incremental Build.
- **Chance of false positives** See my comments on the Incremental Build.

### Which is best?

That depends on the balance between your need for fast feedback (speed), and the resource constraints on your network and build agent(s). If you had lots of resources and wanted both the fast feedback and the robustness of a full rebuild, you could build twice. Perhaps on checkin, do an incremental build, but nightly perform a full checkout and rebuild.

Comment: Incremental checkout + _clean_ rebuild has worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Both, sort of.
We do a scheduled daily full build, and the incremental during the day (gated checkin).

All depends on how big and complex your build is really, but you should err towards full if you are going for one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your granularity of build is, my bias would be to do a full, clean build of that whole component. If that build time is excessively long for a CI loop, consider breaking that component into smaller parts that are dependent on each-other's binaries. In that case, you would build what changed, and any other components that are dependent on the component that changed. In the .Net world, I'm hearing that Nuget is getting increasingly popular for managing those binary dependencies.

I talk a lot more about this strategy in Practice 2 of my [CI pain relief series](http://www.urbancode.com/html/resources/articles/build-pain-relief/).